# Internal Realtek SD card reader rts522a not detected in Ubuntu Studio 14.04 on HP Envy

Tags: 14.04, drivers, hp, realtek, sd-card

I installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04 on a new notebook HP Envy and the internal SD card reader (Realtek rts522a) does not mount. I found 2 drivers to download from Realtek, but they are for rts5227 and rts5229, but not for rts522a.
The card reader worked before I erased Windows and installed Ubuntu. My SD cards are also fine and work in other readers.
How do I find the right driver for this card reader and in which folder should the driver be located?
I have seen several posts about this issue, but nothing has helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running 15.10 on an HP ENVY 13-d008na and just as József assumed: with kernel 4.4.0 it now works like a charm!

Here's a brief note on how to do it, if anyone wants to double-check: [manually upgrading the kernel on ubuntu](http://qnfp.altervista.org/#!notes/kernel-upgrade-on-ubuntu.md)

Comment: Thank you Manuel, this is what I was looking for. I followed the instructions for manually upgrading the kernel, but it failed with too many errors. After I realized I have the lowlatency version installed and downloaded the packages for 64 bit 4.4.0 kernel lowlatency, there were some errors, but the card reader works after the upgrade. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for sharing the feedback about the kernel version. I also run  btrfs as file system and the kernel installed with just one error about initramfs, that was already present with the prior kernel. Strangely, I had several issues with ext4 on that laptop, like crashing when logging out and undefined lags when copying files. So I went to try btrfs and it runs very stable.

Answer (score 0):

I found that neither Ubuntu 14.04 nor 15.10 supports Realtek RTS522a card reader yet (I have the same card reader in HP Pavilion Gamer 15 laptop). Maybe the next Linux kernel version (4.4.x) will support it: http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MFD_RTSX_PCI.html

A launchpad issue is already exists for the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1447878

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) contains kernel version 4.4.x and SD card reader with the chipset above works fine with it.